# Aristotle's Happiness Argument

Tags: ethics, aristotle, virtue-ethics, happiness

In Aristotle's view and Nicomachean Ethics, why does a person always have happiness if he once has happiness?

Comment: Please give a precise reference. Did you look up the statement in the Nicomachean ethics? Are you aware that it is a work of Aristotle?

Answer (score 1):

Aristotle speaks about *eudaimonia* ("ευδαιμονία"). *Εudaimonia* is not just sent by the Gods (good luck, fate etc), but is obtained by a continuous practice of virtue. *Εudaimonia* is an-end-in-itself ("αυτοσκοπός"). **It is not a (passive) state but an (active) process, a doing**. It is an active way of perception of reality.

In Aristotle *happiness* ("ευτυχία") and *eudaimonia* ("ευδαιμονία") are not the same thing. The difference between the two terms, lies in the way of implementation. **While *happiness* is a result of good luck, favorable circumstances, *eudaimonia* needs an internal effort, it is based on each human to obtain it.**